# doubt with range of int variable

Tags: java, integer-overflow

i have a doubt with the range of int value

```
int x=2147483647;     /*NO Error--this number is the maximum range 
                        of int value no error*/
int y=2147483648;     /*Error--one more than the
                        maximum range of int*/
int z=2147483647+1;  /*No Error even though it is one more
                       than the maximum range value*/
```

why ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is an explanation in terms of the Java Language Specification.

The section on integer literals ([JLS 3.10.1](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#3.10.1)) says this:

> The largest decimal literal of type int is `2147483648` (2<sup>31</sup>). All decimal literals from `0` to `2147483647` may appear anywhere an int literal may appear, but the literal `2147483648` may appear only as the operand of the unary negation operator `-`.

So ...

- The first statement is an assignment of a legal integer literal value.  No compilation error.
- The second statement is a compilation error because `2147483648` is not preceded by the unary negation operator.
- The third statement does not contain an integer literal that is out-of-range, so it is not a compilation error from that perspective.

Instead, the third statement is a binary addition expression as described in [JLS 15.18.2](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.18.2).  This states the following about the integer case:

> If an integer addition overflows, then the result is the low-order bits of the mathematical sum as represented in some sufficiently large two's-complement format. If overflow occurs, then the sign of the result is not the same as the sign of the mathematical sum of the two operand values.

Thus, `2147483647 + 1` overflows and wraps around to `-2147483648`.

---

@Peter Lawrey's suggests (flippantly?) that the third statement could be "rewritten by the compiler" as `+2147483648`, resulting in a compilation error.

This is not correct.

There is nothing in the JLS that says that a constant expression can have a different meaning to a non-constant expression.  On the contrary, in cases like `1 / 0` the JLS flips things around and says that the expression is NOT a constant expression BECAUSE it terminates abnormally.  (It is in [JLS 15.28](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.28))

The JLS tries very hard to avoid cases where some Java construct means different things, depending on the compiler.  For instance, it is very particular about the "definite assignment" rules, to avoid the case where only a smart compiler can deduce that variable is always initialized before it is used.  This is a GOOD THING from the perspective of code portability.

The only significant area where there is "wiggle room" for compiler implementers to do platform specific things is in the areas of concurrency and the Java memory model.  And there is a sound pragmatic reason for that - to allow multi-threaded Java applications to run fast on multi-core / multi-processor hardware.

Answer (score 2):

`int` ranges from [`Integer.MIN_VALUE` (-2147483648)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MIN_VALUE) to [`Integer.MAX_VALUE` (2147483647)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE).

However, only `int` literals are checked against the range.

Java does not check that any given constant value expression fits within the range.

Calculations are "allowed" to pass those boundaries, but that will result in an overflow (i.e. only the lower bits of the resulting value will be stored). Therefore, the calculation `2147483647 + 1` **is** well-defined within `int` calculations, and it's -2147483648.

Comment: you gave java does not check any given constant value expression fits with in the range. is that applicable every where

Comment: Yes, constant value expressions will simply overflow, just as runtime calculation does. Only literal values are checked (and will result in a compiler error). Try printing `Double.MIN_VALUE / 10` or `Double.MAX_VALUE + 10 - Double.MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: Good question. That's a special case of allowing a narrowing conversion from `int` to `byte` **iff** the value is within the range: [JLS 5.2](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#5.2) has the details. Without that special case, you'd get an error that you can't assign an `int` to a `byte` without explicit conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Because the third one is called integer overflow. You are doing computations and you overflow. The other ones are just constants.

Answer (score 1):

Because

```
int z=2147483647+1;
```

would be overflowed , which isn't equal to `2147483648`

Comment: It is notionally evaluted at runtime, however the compiler could simplify this expression at compile time. ;) `z == (int) 2147483648`

Comment: But it is constant expression rite.all constant expression will be evaluated at compile time itself know

Comment: An optimisation shouldn't change the behaviour of something.  Just because the compiler can optmise the code shouldn't cause it to produce an error. e.g. `Integer i = 0 / 0;` still compiles even though it produces an aException at runtime. My IDE shows a warning for this expression.

Comment: @Peter - it could, but if it did it would be violating the JLS.

Comment: int z=2147483647+1 in this any how that result will be evaluated at compile time and then it is assigned to int variable now where comes this overflow

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: `0/0` is **not** a [constant expression according to the JLS](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.28), because it "complete abruptly" (i.e. throws an exception).

Comment: @Joachim, excellent point.  However, the general point is that the optimisations the compiler might do won't change the errors it produces.

Comment: @satheesh - because `127 + 1` has type `int`, and Java won't let you assign an `int` to a `byte` without a typecast.

Comment: @Stephen C: wrong. Java **will** let you assign an `int` constant expression to a `byte` without a typecast. Try `byte b = 127+0;`. See my latest comment on my answer (or JLS 5.2) for the reason `127+0` works and `127+1` (or `128`) doesn't.

Comment: @Joachim - I see.  In the case of a *constant* expression where the expression's value is in the range of the target type.

Answer (score 1):

The first two cases seem obvious. The third case will silently overflow. So in such cases you should always handle that in your calling code.

Answer (score 0):

the third expression is an int-based addition, hence it will cast the result to a value within int's range.

Answer (score 0):

The range for `int` is `Integer.MIN_VALUE` to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. Java sliently overflows so the result of a calcuation is not detected by the compiler. (But might be detected by your IDE)

One of the most surprising overflow operations is `-Integer.MIN_VALUE`